# Merging [doc], [document] and [documents] tags

Tags: support, retag-request

[doc](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doc) is just a short version of [document](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/document). Also, [documents](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documents) is the plural form of the latter. They should all be merged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is has been completed. The [doc](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doc) and [document](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/document) tags have been merged in to [documents](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documents) and synonym has been created.